# Issues With Google Log Exporter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

Is it possible to filter out **columns** of **Appengine** **Logs** from streaming into **Big** **Query** when Project Sinks are used in the Google Log Exporter?

Answer (score 1):

We do not currently support partial log entry content in general in Stackdriver Logging. You can see the full spec for the LogSink resource [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/projects.sinks#LogSink).